# Are there equivalents for the GNU __builtin_ia32 functions (for the Visual Studio Compiler)?

Tags: c++, gcc, simd, intrinsics

I want to port an existing C++ code that was optimized for running vector operations with the GNU compiler to compile with the Visual Studio Compiler.

The Program uses specialized GNU single instruction multiple data (SIMD) intrinsic instructions (see e.g. [GCC - Vector Extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)).

Since these intrinsics seem to be GNU compiler only, I would be very happy, if someone knows if there is a way to port the data types and functions to work with other compilers (in my case msvc12).

There are basically two but very closely related questions.
1. Can the following data types be constructed in a similar fashion for other compilers? (These are 16 byte variables containing for example four `int` or sixteen `char`.)

```
   // Integer types
   typedef char     v16qi __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));
   typedef short     v8hi __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));
   typedef int       v4si __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));
   typedef long long v2di __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));

   // Floating point types
   typedef float     v4sf __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));
   typedef double    v2sf __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));
```

2. Where can I find the description and compiler-independent equivalents of the following functions?

   __builtin_ia32_loaddqu, 
   __builtin_ia32_paddsb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_paddusb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_pavgb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_pcmpgtb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_pmovmskb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_psadbw128, 
   __builtin_ia32_psrlwi128, 
   __builtin_ia32_psubsb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_psubusb128, 
   __builtin_ia32_punpckhbw128, 
   __builtin_ia32_pxor128, 
   __builtin_ia32_storedqu

I already intensively searched for this topic but could not find an direct answer to my question. I know that there exist data types that work with msvc12 like `__m128`, `__m128i` and `__m128d` (see e.g. [Microsoft Developer Network - Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t467de55.aspx)), but I could not bring both things together.

Is it possible to "simply" replace the `typedef`s and `__builtin_ia32` functions?

Please comment if I should be more specific on any detail. I tried to keep the question short. 
I would be very grateful for any help! Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Comment: AFAIK, your best bet is to rewrite your code to use Intel's intrinsics, if you need manual vectorization on MSVC.  Use `__m128i` data type, and intrinsics like `_mm_add_epi32`.  See https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/.  (And other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)).

Comment: AFAIK, MSVC doesn't have anything like `typedef short     v8hi __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));` that will let you use the `+` operator to get a PADDW.  But [Agner Fog's (GPLed) vectorclass library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) does provide classes like v4si, and C++ operator overloads.  It's portable to MSVC, gcc, clang, and icc at least.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, @PeterCordes! 
Indeed, the use of something like `v8hi c = a + b` is very handy. I will have a look at the vectorclass library you mentioned, which seems to be really good. This and the links in your answer will help me to proceed. Tanks!

Comment: Just remember that Agner's vectorclass library is GPLed, so you can't use it in closed-source projects.  There are other similar SIMD wrapper libraries, but I haven't looked at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could avoid some of the functions in the code. For the rest the following did the job for me (I could finally identify the corresponding functions in `emmintrin.h` and similar files in the include directory of the MinGW gcc compiler) in combination with the vectorclass library by [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) on which @PeterCordes commented on (thank you for your help).

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define __builtin_ia32_psadbw128(_A, _B)  _mm_sad_epu8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_paddsb128(_A, _B)  _mm_adds_epi8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_pmovmskb128(_A)    _mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i) _A)
#define __builtin_ia32_pcmpgtb128(_A, _B) _mm_cmpgt_epi8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_psubsb128(_A, _B)  _mm_subs_epi8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_psubusb128(_A, _B) _mm_subs_epu8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_pavgb128(_A, _B)   _mm_avg_epu8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_paddusb128(_A, _B) _mm_adds_epu8((__m128i) _A, (__m128i) _B)
#define __builtin_ia32_psrlwi128(_A, _B)  _mm_srli_epi16((__m128i) _A, _B)
#define __builtin_popcountll(_X)          _mm_popcnt_u64((unsigned long long) _X)
#endif
```

Probably, inline functions would be more elegant than the above `define`s.

Comment: Most people would do it the other way around, and use Intel's intrinsics in their code.  I guess you're doing it the other way so you can use GNU C native vectors so operators like `+` use the right element size.